# Adding an image using file upload control in laravel blade view with vuejs?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is my laravel blade view from where i am fetching the information

```
<form @submit="formSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
                        @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label>Select Store</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="store_id" v-model="form.store_id" required>
                                       <option v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id" v-bind:value="store.id">@{{store.channel_id}}</option>
                                    </select>   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label>Recorded Date</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="flatpickr form-control" v-model="form.recorded_date" name="recorded_date" required> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label>Upload Bank Receipt</label>
                                    <input class="form-control-file" type="file" @change="handleUpload($event.target.files)" required>   
                                </div>
                            </div> 
</form> 
<script>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function() {
    },
    data: {
        stores: {!! $stores !!},
        users: {!! $users !!},
        form: {
            user_id: '',
            recorded_date: '',
            photo: null,
            store_id: '',
            cashoutexpenses: []
        }, 
        
    },
    methods: {
        handleUpload(files) {
          this.form.photo = files[0];
        },
        formSubmit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           axios.post('/cashoutdetails/store',{
                data: this.form,
            })
            .then(response => {
                $(location).attr('href', '/cashoutdetails')
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('Error');
            }); 
        }
    }
})

</script>
```

Below is my controller code --

```
         $data = $request->data;
       //$imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
       //$request->image->move(storage_path('app/public/bankreceipt'), $imageName);
       $contents = file_get_contents($request->image->path());
       $fileName = time().'.'.$data['bank_receipt']->extension();
       return $fileName;
       $cashout_details = CashOutDetail::create([
           'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
           'store_id' => $data['store_id'],
           'recorded_date' => $data['recorded_date'],
           'bank_receipt'=> $fileName,
       ]);
```

i am getting error as Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null or if i use path -- then path as null while working with file upload control rest information is being stored in database if i exclude file upload control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks !! But again it didnt work .. Below is the code which works -

```
 formSubmit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentObj = this;
           // let data = new FormData();
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('store_id', this.form.store_id);
            formData.append('recorded_date', this.form.recorded_date);
            formData.append('photo', this.form.photo); 
            formData.append('closing_report_total', this.form.closing_report_total);
            formData.append('total_deposit', this.form.total_deposit);
            formData.append('difference', this.form.difference);
            formData.append('form.cashoutexpenses', this.form.cashoutexpenses);
            formData.append('prepared_by', this.form.prepared_by);
            formData.append('deposited_by', this.form.deposited_by);
            formData.append('deposit_date', this.form.deposit_date);
            formData.append('reference_number', this.form.reference_number);
            formData.append('comments', this.form.comments);
            let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
            axios.post('/cashoutdetails/store', formData ,config)
            .then(response => {
                //$(location).attr('href', '/cashoutdetails')
                alert('data saved');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('Error');
            }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when getting this errors, try to debug your code, if you `dd($data['bank_receipt'])` you will probably see that the request is null, you can also do `dd(request()->all())` to see exacly what are you receiving, combined with inspecting the element and going to network tab to see what are the browser sending

I'm pretty sure that your problem is becase of the `Content-Type` when sending files, you must send it as `multipart/form-data`, as an in a normal html form request you would add the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` you have to do the same on an javascript resquest

try this out, as the third parameter you can pass aditional options to the request

```
axios.post('/cashoutdetails/store', {
    data: this.form,
}, {
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
}).then(...
```

> NOTICE: this header should be passed only if you're sending a file, so if there is a world where the user can send the request without the file, you have to test it

also you're passing the parameter as `photo` and never trying to get this parameter on your controller code, that confusing